# Flutter Web Handling URLs

Tags: flutter, web, url, routes, navigation

I have a website. In the future there will be thousands of pages. And i don't know how to handle all pages for best navigation. I created 2 classes as shown in below.

```
class RoutePaths {
  static const Homepage = '/';
  static const Calculations = '/calculations';
  static const MathCalculations = '/calculations/math-calculation';
  static const PhysicsCalculations =
      '/calculations/physics-calculation';
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case RoutePaths.Homepage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (_) => const Homepage(),
        );
      case RoutePaths.Calculations:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (_) => const Calculations(),
        );
      case RoutePaths.MathCalculations:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (_) => const MathCalculations(),
        );
      case RoutePaths.PhysicsCalculations:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (_) => const PhysicsCalculations(),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (_) => const Homepage(),
        );
    }
  }
```

In the first class there are static names of pages. In the second class there are navigations. If there will be 10.000 pages then i should create 10.000 static names in the first class? If yes, i think this is big load for the website. And if i don't use static variables, i have to copy paste route names to use in different classes and when i want to change route names, it will be very hard. And similarly 10000 lines for navigation is also much. What is the best solution for big projects?

Comment: I would say practice navigator 2 for flutter-web app

Comment: I will search about this.

Answer (score 0):

Create other class which contain list  of all class widgets constructor
Then just access this from other class is very best thing

Comment: I don't know how to do this.